# Initializing a large bit number as zero

Tags: verilog, clock, binary

Is there a more efficient way of registering an initial value for a variable than

```
reg [3:0] COUNT = 4'b0000;
```

where in this case if I were to define say a 32-bit COUNT I would need to write 32'b(32 zeroes here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing says that you always need to specify all the zeros in binary base. In fact you can write it like this:

```
reg [31:0] COUNT = 32'd0;
```

....using a decimal base. The Verilog will extend that decimal zero out to the specified 32 bit width.

Comment: `32'b0` will work just as well, so will `32'h0`. Verilog will pad any 'unsigned' constant with zeros, and any 'signed' constant with copies of the MSB.

Comment: `reg [WIDTH -1: 0] count = {WIDTH{1'b0}}` can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog always pads narrow integral values with zeros on the left when assigning to wider variables, and truncates on the left when assigning wider to narrower variables. So you could have written

```
reg [31:0] COUNT = 0;
```

Verilog sign extends when the variables are all signed data types. There rules get trickier when you mix operands of signed and unsigned types.

Comment: Not specifying a width at all is not the best option. By default constants are 32bit wide, so if you tried this with a 16bit number you would get synthesizer warnings about constants being truncated to fit.